# Default type of keyof T cannot be used to index type T

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I am trying to refactor this code to use static method because the class is only used for namespace and `Query.equal<TodoModel>(...)` is better than `(new Query<TodoModel>).equal(...)`

```js
interface TodoModel {
    title: string;
    timeLeft: number;
    done: boolean;
}

class Query<T> {
    equal<K extends keyof T>(attr: K, val: T[K]) {
        return `${String(attr)}==${val}`;
    }
    // other methods for notEqual, lessThan, greaterThan, contains etc.
}

let q = (new Query<TodoModel>)
q.equal("unknownKey", 45) // unknownKey gives error

q.equal("title", 765)     // 765 is the wrong type
q.equal("title", "write notes")    // no errors
```

I tried:

```js
class Query2 {
    static equal<T, K = keyof T>(attr: K, val: T[K]) {
        return `${String(attr)}==${val}`;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error saying K cannot be used to index T. Why would that be and is there a solution for this?

I use default type because with extends (`equal<T, K extends keyof T>`) the usage would be `Query2.equal<TodoModel, "title">("title", "write notes")` where the key needs to be repeated.

Here's the full typescript playground: [Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFpK6dv4YpykCgSgBIFMA2AHbAJwGdVUBLAOwBdiAzAQwGNtQAVAewBNOBZHnlABvVKHGgaFGrmwAuUCRpFqAcwDcYiVIC22ADLZ6NBVQCuOgEbFNE0LyrzQlzp1mMqmgL7lmuRiQkHDycoBQ6+LJ6tEFcvALceKJ2UjJOSipUGlriugZGJqDmVjY59pyOCi5u2B62EswVGWbMNJxEABSpsgoZagA0kuH5xqYW1kSDDk7V7lQAlCJlKQAWFCQAdN1sALxDafV2uWubeYbGoHtnBYdHNCcb05fljrc+PuhgKN8-v3-fn1AAEEaHQIjRQABGBQAd3aAGsgpYzBDHNhuEFGKBOJYAFbYVqoPwBIIARTMxAAngAedgAPiWdmwAEczIxcNSANKgbAADzoVAxoHh2EpnHoHDpHUYoKICk5gwAbuyFOwANqcgC6i2SR3ERGwNDMRCooAABgASYQAZWUamlsvmXh2OytytwXjNb1QH1kEOZzw6jhhoHJVNpIQSeDp8w2LLZuFQzI6ACIzFR4VRODCqJzRSnBgAWACs83IyZT2wLoBTMJUdCKnDoJBTZYrVcGAHYAGylpOpjuSIgUsv9yvDc40au1+tsLPN1tj67Gas9vvticFavKEfl1PTad16RzpvYFtt-cVbCr3sXlMHwY77CjjD-N-vj9oDAgsH4CEAJlVNUaEpQhxVAGVlE1MIggqXBKR5d02TobhsSoVhUHodNWgoCpQFZKkAFFWXZWkpUguVhVFcD2CVFUOGA0DsHAijtUZCQDSNE1zStW1MlUB1lCdF03XZT0fXLCkiEpYiEwjeJBFwKU0wzLMczzSlqxLUcCOk2TSLifhFOUwcZ2PRsFzbKSZJIjlDKjJSB2kWQb3Xaz9LsyNjKctJt2HZ9JKI2z5KMxJHPHPRJ0PWcLLPRddJsuT7O8iKRinLtbyTdzguSsKTM3FdH38nTsqSry8svRxovM+c4qsoKyoUir7yvVz6r0nLyujSrryK3dAU-Qahvfchv1BbBwVAABmWFpBWZ5VAoRUzwg01iCIdp1FAGE5p5flsEFII0VQtpQANQgZSoykyGJQJQ2s-92PEJQZQoZgeRywZuT2EUxQlelBMohVQHdICtR1ZYOMNY1TUtG07SyQHhNdYR3U9b0PluslrKmp7FBoV73vjAyvr2gUhV+mjyNleU6NwMG2N1PVOJhnj4f4pHnRRtGvTKd5yD9fDHr2MNpKmuNbKTf9U3TTNs1zfMiz7KWQocwZx18-LfPVo8G1q88VdyvB1arLWXIy9d-1VxSTec68zd6od+uZK2jdwW3Iq3fLPcKmtdZPSzDa692a2XKdvbStqg6a43Q4K8OnJ99KnYC6PQtjlqquUh8-Zi-X4td4P1YPbPWotttC5jkPM-tnq-P68gtCAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYe82W) solve your problem? If yes, I will write up an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame I see this exact wording pretty often, do you use some plugin for that or something?

Comment: @Dimava I wish I had one. I just manually type it every time :D

Comment: @wonderflame then gonna ask jcalz next time I see hin answering

Comment: @wonderflame for context, there is LinkShortener plugin in typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: @wonderflame found https://greasyfork.org/ru/scripts/433721-stack-exchange-comment-template-context-menu

Comment: @Dimava, thanks for sharing! If he does have something, then let me know

Comment: What about ```<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>```? I feel like this should be the correct answer for this question, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Islingre it requires to provide two generic args, whule OP wants to provide one and infer 2nd from call

Comment: @Dimava One does not need to provide 2 arguments. Because the second has a default. But I found a different shortcoming of it: if no explicit type is provided for ```K``` (and OP surely does not want to provide one), ```K``` cannot be inferred automatically from the call but will stay ```keyof T```. Thus, the type of ```val```, ```T[K]```, is the union of the types of all properties of ```T``` and not just the one for the given ```attr```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only to mention the model and not the type, the possible solution is to have a union of all possible key-value pairs, which can be achieved with the following type:

```
type UnionArgs<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T];
```

Usage:

```
// ["title", string] | ["timeLeft", number] | ["done", boolean]
type Result = UnionArgs<TodoModel>
```

The only thing left is to update the method/function as follows:

```
function queryEqual<T>(...args: UnionArgs<T>) {
  return `${String(args[0])}==${args[1]}`;
}
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYe82W)

Comment: Using this, autocomplete for parameter of `queryEqual(` shows args_0 and args_1. Is there a way to make it say attr and val like it used to?

Comment: Try this: `type UnionArgs<T> = {[K in keyof T]: [attr: K, value: T[K]];}[keyof T];`