# Avoid repeating generic type on function call

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I have a query class with static methods and the output of those are parameters to another function.

```js
type ModelType = { [key: string]: unknown };
type IsNullStr<T extends ModelType> = `isNull("${string & keyof T}")`;

declare class Query {
  static isNull: <T extends ModelType>(attribute: string & keyof T) => IsNullStr<T>;
}

type TodoList = { id: string; };

declare function listDocuments<T extends ModelType>(queries: IsNullStr<T>): void;

listDocuments<TodoList>(Query.isNull<TodoList>("id"));
listDocuments<TodoList>(Query.isNull("id"));
```

The second call fails to infer Query.isNull(...) as Query.isNull(...). Why would that be?

Typescript playground: https://tsplay.dev/mpxv7m

Comment: A slightly different version of isNull like https://tsplay.dev/mAxvZN seems to work. I am trying to understand why. Its fine if it can't be done.

Comment: Could we reduce this to a more minimal [mre] like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpxv7m) shows?  I just want to make sure we're not adding complexity that doesn't need to be here.  (Also types are conventionally named like `IsNullStr<T>` and not `isNullStr<T>`; could we [edit] those to be more conventional and less distracting?)

Comment: @Nevus It seems that you have figured it out yourself :D

Comment: @wonderflame I need T to be available and cannot use the new version. This is a continuation of another question you answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76180903/10168590

Comment: @wonderflame Could you repost link to your earlier playground?

Comment: @Nevus sure, here you go [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mblG9w)